# MySQL - Trigger to delete previous record

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm trying to create a trigger that will allow only one record in a database, so it would delete any previous records.
But currently, it doesn't allow me to insert anything it, because it's instantly deleted.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER test_insert 
BEFORE INSERT ON test
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
DELETE FROM test WHERE id = NEW.id - 1;
END$$
```

How would I delete a previously (or all previous) inserted record?

Comment: can you give sample records with desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"But currently, it doesn't allow me to insert anything it, because it's instantly deleted."

Acutally, when you do an INSERT, the execution of your trigger should be throwing exception:

```
Error Code: 1442
Can't update table 'test' in stored function/trigger because it is
  already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.
```

(Unless something is radically different in a newer version of MySQL.)

---

The operation you want to perform (i.e. deleting rows from the same table you are inserting into) cannot be done in a MySQL trigger.

You could use a combination of a UNIQUE KEY and a BEFORE INSERT trigger to prevent more than one row from being inserted.  The BEFORE INSERT trigger could set the value of the column that has a unique 
key on it to be a static value, then the INSERT statement would throw a duplicate key ("Duplicate entry") exception.

Then, you could use an `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...` statement to update the values of columns other than the unique id, e.g.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `test_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON test
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
   SET NEW.id := 1;
END

ALTER TABLE test ADD UNIQUE KEY (id);

INSERT INTO test (somecol) VALUES ('someval')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE somecol = VALUES(somecol) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

To do that you first need to find some value at which you want to delete all and insert for. This way you don't need a trigger, you simply delete all previous cases and then add a new row. Unless for some reason unexplained from your code you would need a trigger a simple solution in your loop could work Like:

```
$query = mysql_query("DELETE FROM test WHERE id = NEW.id -1");
$new_id = $new.id -1;
$query2 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO test VALUES('$new_id','$var1','$var2'));
```